# How to avoid if-else statements that do the same thing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement

I'm trying to minimize a little js program, and I came across this problem: I do not want to write a lot of `if-else` statements that they all do the same thing. Is there an elegant way to rewrite this function?

```
function advance_bthrads(toCompare, arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(element) {
        if (element.value) {
            let wf = element.value['wait_for'];
            let req = element.value['request'];
            if (wf && req) {
                if (toCompare === wf[0] || toCompare === req[0]) {
                    element = update_element(element);
                }
            } else if (wf) {
                if (toCompare === wf[0]) {
                    element = update_element(element);
                }
            } else if (req) {
                if (toCompare === req[0]) {
                    element = update_element(element);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: btw, this `element = update_element(element);` does not work. maybe `update_element(...)` updates the element, but not the assignment.

Comment: `if((wf && wf[0] == toCompare) || (req && toCompare == req[0])) element = update_element(element);` should give the same result

Comment: @JackBashford Please don't retag to `[ecmascript-6]` unnecessarily. From the [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ecmascript-6/info) wiki: "*Only use this tag where the question specifically relates to new features or technical changes provided in ECMAScript 2015*"

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` doesn't return anything - use `map`:

```
arr = arr.map(element => {
  if (element.value) {
    let [wf] = element.value['wait_for'] || [0];
    let [req] = element.value['request'] || [0];
    if (wf && req && [wf, req].includes(toCompare)) element = update_element(element);
  }
  return element;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring for a moment the fact that `element = update_element(element);` achieves nothing (as you're just updating the local `element`, not what it references) your condition can be reduced to simply

```
if((wf && wf[0] == toCompare) || (req && toCompare == req[0]))
```

Since the basic check is whether `toCompare` equals either `wf[0]` or `req[0]` and you basically add a check to see if `wf` and `req` exist.

At this point you can use `map` instead of `forEach` to get the result you want. Notice you have to `return` the map, and whatever function calls `advance_bthreads` needs to reassign the result (i.e. `arr = advance_bthreads(toCompare, arr);`)

```
function advance_bthrads(toCompare, arr) {
    return arr.map(function(element) { // NOTICE you have to return the result
        if (element.value) {
            let wf = element.value['wait_for'];
            let req = element.value['request'];
            if((wf && wf[0] == toCompare) || (req && toCompare == req[0]))
                element = update_element(element);
        }
        return element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could short it a bit by returning early and combining the conditions.

BTW, the assignment does not work as intended, you need to use the element of the array with an index.

If `update_element` mutates `element`, then no assignment is necessary.

```js
function advance_bthrads(toCompare, arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        if (!element.value) return;
        let wf = element.value['wait_for'];
        let req = element.value['request'];
        if (wf && toCompare === wf[0] || req && toCompare === req[0]) {
            array[index] = update_element(element);
        }
    });
    return arr;
}
```